# Embed Dictionary into VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource

I want to embed a dictionary.txt which my program uses a streamreader object to parse. I tried to add it to resources but then the streamreader had an error. How can it be properly done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to embed the file in your assembly (add to project and goto Properties for the file, and set **Build Action** to "Embedded Resource").

Then you need to access and read it's contents using [GetManifestResourceStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(VS.85).aspx):

[Getting an embedded resource file out of an assembly](http://www.csharper.net/blog/getting_an_embedded_resource_file_out_of_an_assembly.aspx)

This article might be of interest: [Microsoft .NET Framework Resource Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950960.aspx)